# Does this sequence of sets eventually contain all primes?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I was on Reddit earlier and answered a question about the usual proof that there are infinitely many primes: multiply any finite set of them, add 1, factor, and you get factors that are not in the set.

But a question occurred to me that I've never seen discussed, and I'm curious if any work has been done or if a conclusive answer has been reached. The question relates to the following sequence. Define:

$S_0 = \{2\}$

$S_n = S_{n-1}\cup T_{n-1}$

where $T_{n-1}$ is defined as the set of prime factors of $\Pi S_{n-1}+1$ (is there a standard notation for "the set of prime factors of n?"). The question is, do all primes eventually appear in one of the $S_n$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Background: This is closely related to the [Euclid-Mullin sequence](http://oeis.org/A000945), and this other [version](http://oeis.org/A000946), which are the smallest and largest prime factors of $\prod p_i+1$, respectively.

---

A complete answer to the question posed can be found in the following paper ([link](http://www.integers-ejcnt.org/vol12a.html)):

A. R. Booker, On Mullin's second sequence of primes, Integers, 12A (2012), article A4.

Specifically, see p.3, Variant #2.  This is precisely the question of OP, and the answer is "a very thin subset of the primes", because each prime generated divides a Sylvester number, and the latter were proven to be sparse in the following paper, for which I do not have a link.

R. W. K. Odoni.  On the prime divisors of the sequence $w_{n+1}  = 1 + w_1 \cdots w_n$.  J. London Math. Soc. (2), 32(1):1–11, 1985.

Comment: There is a difference, the OEIS sequence only includes the smallest prime factor of $\prod p_i+1$, while OP's question includes all prime factors.  If this sequence includes all primes, that would answer the original question in the affirmative, but it is possible that not all primes are in this sequence but are in OP's list. Still, this is helpful.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, my pleasure.

Comment: What is the smallest prime that does not appear and how do you prove it?

Comment: This may be answered in Odoni's paper.  I don't know, as I don't currently have access to it.